# How to prevent "for" from dividing directory names?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to list all hidden directories with a "for" loop:

```
for i in ``ls -a | grep '^\.'` `;
do 
    echo $i
done
```

The problem is that the loop divides some directory names in two.

For example: `ls -a | grep '^\.'` gives me

```
.
..
.Deleted Items
.Drafts 
.Junk
.Junk E-mail
.Sent
.Sent Items
.Trash
```

But my loop gives me:

```
.
..
.Deleted
Items
.Drafts
.Junk
.Junk
E-mail
.Sent
.Sent
Items
.Trash
```

How do I improve my script, so that it doesn't divide directory names?

Comment: You'll likely have better luck on Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-to-escape-white-space-in-bash-loop-list

Comment: Short of it use the IFS variable. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the `ls` command as the shell will do the expansion for you and you should quote `"` the variable

```
for i in .*/
do
echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: But this work to : SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

for i in `ls -a | grep '^\.'`;
do 
echo "$i"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a specific need for 'for' you could try a while loop:

```
ls -d .* | while read Name  
do  
    echo "$Name"  
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways around this, from find, to extra quoting, etc.

Personally, I find it useful to modify the IFS variable.  IFS is used to determine what the break character is between list items for `for` and the like.  So, set IFS to be a newline via `IFS=$'\n'`.  This will make the `for` loop read until the end of a line of input, before starting a new item in its list.  It may not be the easiest way to solve this specific issue,  (Iain's answer is more elegant) but I've found it quite useful in a number of situations.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem some days ago and [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2213/copy-recursively-except-hidden-directory) was very helpful. Hope you find inspiration there.